# How to 'press key' automatically when an external program is open?

Tags: python

I have a script that starts a external program with Python.  I am trying to press different keys to capture statistics when the external program is open.

I tried to do something like this :

```py
  with open(listFix[e] + "otherStats.txt" ,"w") as secondOutput :
        command2 = "{0} --screen 0 --window 0 0 960 540 s s s S {1}".format(screenCommand,listFix[e])
        processText = subprocess.Popen(command2,stdout=secondOutput)
        time.sleep(4)
        processText.kill()
```

But that doesn't work. When I do it manually, the expected output is written to the console.

`( i want the s s s S key to be pressed )`

How can I resolve this?

Comment: _"but that doesnt work."_ is a insubstantial

Comment: Yes, can you please say what happens when `it doesn't work` ? Does it crash ? Does it raise an exception, does it continue as if you were doing nothing ?

Comment: No just nothing happend, when i dot it manually it  write on the console the output i want @JosephBudin

Comment: Then, I think you can edit your question to add this piece of information

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `Popen.comunicate` for this. it allow you send `stdin` values and get the `stdout` and `stderr` of the input from the process, its probably the best practice here, the documenation also tells as to use it and nit use `stdin.write`:

`Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.`

you can read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)

the values you pass in the cmd line is the agruments for the program, not the input. thats mean that your porgram just try to run the command right now with those arguments